# Force a ungraceful disconnect in MQTT (to trigger a last-will message)

Tags: python, mqtt

In testing, I'd like to test some last-will behaviour between my Python MQTT client and broker (mosquitto). Both are on the same machine. How can I simulate / force a disconnect within Python between the client and broker?

Ideally, my Python script looks something like:

```py
client = Client("localhost")
client.will_set(**last_will)
client.connect()

# force a disconnect here? 
# listen for the last will
# allow connection again

# at this point, client should have reconnected and I can continue
...
client.subscribe(...)
...
```

Comment: Your work flow here is flawed, there is no way for the disconnected client to receive the LWT as it is by definition, disconnected.... It might be better if you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: I was going to catch it with another client. But, the question I am really wondering about is: does the last-will fire only once per connection? And if so, is it possible to reset the last-will after a reconnection?

Comment: It fires once per connection and No you can not change it. (a reconnection is a new connection)

Answer (score 0):

Just kill the python process.

`kill -9 [pid of python]`

Comment: I thought of this, but I want to simulate it in the Python script, so to test the reconnect & disconnect behaviour. Ex: client connects, cut connection, watch last-will, allow connection, client reconnects, cut connection, ...

Comment: Those constraints should really have been in the question

Comment: I agree, my question was lacking. I've updated it